# How to destroy data in id when select radio button like this function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How to destroy data in id when select radio button like this function ?

.....................................................................................................................................................................

First load page index.php,

1. press `Check1` button, you will see text `PRODUCTS DATA OK`
2. checked radio button `SECOND RADIO`
3. checked radio button `FIRST RADIO`
4. you will see text `PRODUCTS DATA OK`

this is my question in step `2. checked radio button SECOND RADIO` 
After checked radio button `SECOND RADIO`, i want to destroy text `PRODUCTS DATA OK`
that store in `<p id="myplace_data1"></p>`

How can i do that ?

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".radio_id").click(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="first"){
                $("#second_checkbox").hide();                
                $("#first_checkbox_display").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="second"){
                $("#first_checkbox_display").hide();                
                $("#second_checkbox").show();    
            }
        });
    });
</script>


<form id="first_checkbox_display" name="form1" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);" style=" margin: 0px; " >
<input type="text" name="products_id" value="1294759">
<input type="text" name="products_color" value="red">
<input type="text" name="products_type" value="electronic">
<input type="button" value="Check1" onclick="doajax_products_check()"/>
<p id="myplace_data1"></p>
</form>



<form id="second_checkbox" name="form2" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);" style=" display: none; margin: 0px; " >
<input type="text" name="products_id" value="0000000">
<input type="text" name="products_color" value="iiiiiii">
<input type="text" name="products_type" value="aaaaaaa">
<input type="button" value="Check2" onclick="doajax_products_check2()"/>
<p id="myplace_data2"></p>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<label><input type="radio" class="radio_id" name="colorRadio" value="first" checked >FIRST RADIO</label>
<br>
<label><input type="radio" class="radio_id" name="colorRadio" value="second">SECOND RADIO</label>




<script language="javascript">
function createAjax() 
{
    var request = false;
        try {
                request = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
            }
        catch (err2) 
            {
                try 
                    {
                        request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                    }
                catch (err3) 
                    {
                try 
                           {
                    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                   }
                catch (err1) 
                   {
                    request = false;
                   }
                    }
            }
    return request;
}
</script>



<script language="javascript">
function doajax_products_check(mydata){
 var ajax1=createAjax(); 
 ajax1.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if(ajax1.readyState==4 && ajax1.status==200){
   document.getElementById('myplace_data1').innerHTML=ajax1.responseText;
  }else{
   return false;
  }
 }
 ajax1.open("POST","data.php",true);
 ajax1.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
 ajax1.send("products_color="+document.form1.products_color.value+"&products_type="+document.form1.products_type.value+"&products_id="+document.form1.products_id.value);
}
</script>









<script language="javascript">
function doajax_products_check2(mydata){
 var ajax1=createAjax(); 
 ajax1.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if(ajax1.readyState==4 && ajax1.status==200){
   document.getElementById('myplace_data2').innerHTML=ajax1.responseText;
  }else{
   return false;
  }
 }
 ajax1.open("POST","data.php",true);
 ajax1.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
 ajax1.send("products_color="+document.form2.products_color.value+"&products_type="+document.form2.products_type.value+"&products_id="+document.form2.products_id.value);
}
</script>
```

data.php

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST['products_color']))
    {
        if ( $_POST['products_id'] != '' )
            { 
                if ( $_POST['products_type'] != '' )
                    {  
?>
                        <span class="taken_domain" style=" display: block; margin: 0 auto; " >PRODUCTS DATA OK</span> 
<?PHP
                    }
                 else
                    {
?>
                        <span class="taken_domain" style=" display: block; margin: 0 auto; " >NO PRODUCTS type</span> 
<?PHP
                    }
            }
        else
            { 
?>             
                <span class="taken_domain" style=" display: block; margin: 0 auto; " >NO PRODUCTS ID</span>             
<?PHP                
            }
    }
else
    {
?>
        <span class="taken_domain" style=" display: block; margin: 0 auto; " >NO PRODUCTS COLOR</span>    
<?PHP    
    }    
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test for the checked state and the set the HTML to be blank -

```
if( $('input[value="second"]').is(':checked') ){
    $('#myplace_data1').html('');
    var products_id = ?; // you'll have to get the product id here
    // make AJAX call here...
    $.post( "delete_product.php", { products_id: products_id, user: user_id } );
}
```

All you have to do is create a PHP file that connects to the database and runs the query.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: It's OK, Work GOOD ^^

Comment: And i have 1 question. could you please advice me ?

Comment: Sure, what's the question?

Comment: after check radio button i want to delete mysql like this `$sql = "DELETE FROM procust_store 
WHERE products_id = '$_POST[products_id]' AND user = '$id' ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($sql);`  How can i do ?

Comment: See my edit above: make an AJAX call to your PHP script that will run the query to perform the delete.

Comment: i not use to do that something like ajax call for delete mysql , Could you please give me some code ?

Comment: I made edits to the code, that should get you started. Please don't forget to accept the answer by checking the checkmark next to the answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: in PHP file , check $_POST value if $_POST value != '' go to delete mysql , it's OK ?

Comment: I would guess that it is @papmooo but cannot be sure because I am not familiar with your whole application.